# No instance of type variable V,K exist so that HashMultiMap<V,K> conforms to MultiMap<..,..>

Tags: java, guava

```
MultiMap<Integer, String> mm = HashMultimap.create();
```

I get a red line under `create()` saying :

"no instance of type variable V,K exist so that HashMultiMap conforms to MultiMap".

Can anyone help? I'm in dilemma on what to do next.

Comment: It should be `Multimap` with a lower case `m` in the middle - check your imports.

Comment: I guess you have Apache Commons Collections on your classpath as well, as assylias said, it has to be `Multimap` (`MultiMap` is probably the Apache one).

Comment: assylias is right..intellij didnt hesitate to import this class for me.

Comment: @rjbaj : have you tried `Ctrl-Alt-Space`?

Comment: Yes, usually pressing enter did the job. debugging only showed the above error. So, i guess this was just an embarrassing typo. Thanks assylias , Thomas anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check your imports and class/interface names: `MultiMap` and `HashMultimap` should be imported from the same framework.

For instance `Apache Collections` has `MultiMap` and `Guava` has `Multimap` - typo and wrong import is likely to happen.